# How to modify attributes of forms generated by webapp (Google App Engine)?

Tags: google-app-engine, forms, web-applications

Here are model and form classes from **example:**

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html

```
class Item(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  quantity = db.IntegerProperty(default=1)
  target_price = db.FloatProperty()
  priority = db.StringProperty(default='Medium',choices=[
    'High', 'Medium', 'Low'])
  entry_time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  added_by = db.UserProperty()

class ItemForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Item
    exclude = ['added_by']
```

It will be rendered as table rows.

Can I change how they will be rendered (change width or make it to be list instead of table row or anything…)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Django forms docs, [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/forms/). The docs are for 1.0, but most of it applies to the 0.91 version bundled with App Engine, too.

The short answer to your question: `form.as_p` will generate an HTML representation of the form as a series of <p> tags, while `form.as_ul` will generate a series of <ul> tags and `form.as_table` will generate a table.

Comment: Thanks I realized that I've used ModelForm instead of just forms/newforms.

Comment: Are there any forms/newforms inside google.appengine.ext or I must use "from django import newforms" ?

Comment: The latter. The modules in appengine.ext are stuff that was written by Google - some of interacts with Django.

Comment: And you can continue to use ModelForm - as_p, etc should work fine with it.